# Using LSTM for binary classification

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have time series data of size 100000*5. 100000 samples and five variables.I have labeled each 100000 samples as either 0 or 1. i.e. binary classification.
I want to train it using LSTM , because of the time series nature of data.I have seen examples of LSTM for time series prediction, Is it suitable to use it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your needs.

LSTM is best suited for sequence models, like time series you said, and your description don't look a time series.

Any way, you may use LSTM for time series, not for prediction, but for classification like [this article](http://machinelearningmastery.com/sequence-classification-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/).

In my experience, for binary classification having only 5 features you could find better methods, will consume more memory thant other methods, and could get worst results.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can see it from a different perspective, i.e. instead of having 10,000 **labeled** samples of **5 variables**, you should treat it as 10,000 **unlabeled** samples of **6 variables**, where the 6th variable is the label.

Therefore, you can train your LSTM as a **multivariate predictor** for your 6th variable, that is the sample label and compare with the ground truth during testing to evaluate its performance.